# Javascript long else / if statement in a shortest way

Tags: javascript, if-statement, short

I have written an else / if statement in my plugin but for optimization (less code) I want it to be shorter.

```
if ( self.first() ) {

    if ( self.second() ) {
        self.run();
    }
    else {
        self.other_run();
    }

}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Example

```
if ( check cookie is true ) {
    if ( check timezone is true  ) {
     run sth
    }
    else {
     run other thing
    }
}
else {
    do nothing
}
```

What about?

```
if ( self.first() ) {
    self.second ? self.run() : self.other_run();
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Is it ok to write it like that?

```
return self.first() ? ( self.second() ? self.run() : self.other_run() ) : false;
```

Comment: That won't necessarily run any faster. Also, what about the `return` statement?

Comment: As of your edit, those still don't do quite the same thing. The first version doesn't return if `self.first()` is true; the second version does (it returns whatever either `run` or `other_run` returns).

Comment: Less code is usually great, but in big logical scenarios like this, you'll only confuse & make the logic harder to read in the future (and especially for other programmers). I still believe the best way would be the first way.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.first() ? ( self.second() ? self.run() : self.other_run() ) : false;
```

Should work fine, but I'm not sure why you'd want to obfuscate your code like that.

Answer (score 0):

(Keep in mind that "shorter" code isn't always "better" code.)

That may work, with some explicit parenthesis to separate your wrapped statements.  Though it's not really easier to read/understand.  How about something like this?:

```
if (self.first() && self.second()) {
    self.run();
    return;
}
if (self.first()) {
    self.other_run();
    return;
}
return false;
```

This follows Martin Fowler's refactoring pattern called [Replace Nested Conditional With Guard Clauses](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html).

This also makes it more clear that your function isn't *always* returning a boolean value.  (Something I didn't immediately notice until I wrote this.)  Perhaps you mean to do so (a bug which wasn't noticed in the overly-brief version of the code)?:

```
if (self.first() && self.second()) {
    self.run();
    return true;
}
if (self.first()) {
    self.other_run();
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Naturally, this code is obviously fake just to demonstrate a point.  But if the conditional clauses do start to get unwieldy, you can always extract them into their own functions:

```
if (somethingIsTrue()) {
    self.run();
    return true;
}
if (somethingElseIsTrue()) {
    self.other_run();
    return true;
}
return false;
```